# Computing decay of Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I know that if $f\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, then the Fourier coefficients obey the inequality $|f_k|\leq \frac{M}{|k|^n}$ where $k$ denotes the $kth$ Fourier coefficient and $M=sup_x|f^{(n)}(x)|$.

Can someone provide a detailed proof as to how we derive the inequalities for the following classes of functions:

Holder continuous: $|f_k|\leq \frac{K}{|k|^\alpha}$ where $K$ is the multiplicative constant, and $\alpha$ is the Holder exponent.

Bounded variation: $|f_k|\leq \frac{var(f)}{2\pi|k|}$

I am not sure exactly how these are computed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a function on the circle $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ that is in $L^1$. Let $k > 0$ WLOG. One can compute
$$ \begin{aligned}
\hat{f}(k) &:= \int_{0}^1 e^{-2\pi i k y} f(y) dy = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \int_{k^{-1} j}^{k^{-1} (j+1)} e^{-2\pi i k y} f(y) dy \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \int_{k^{-1} j}^{k^{-1} (j+1)} e^{-2\pi i k y} (f(y) - f(k^{-1} j)) dy
\end{aligned}$$
and so
$$
\lvert \hat{f}(k) \rvert \leq \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \int_{k^{-1} j}^{k^{-1} (j+1)} \lvert f(y) - f(k^{-1} j) \rvert dy.
$$

Now if $f$ is $\alpha$ Holder continuous with constant $K$, we have
$$
\lvert \hat{f}(k) \rvert  \leq \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} k^{-1} \cdot K \cdot k^{-\alpha} \leq K k^{-\alpha}.
$$
Let $f$ be of bounded variation instead. Use the facts
$$
\int_{k^{-1} j}^{k^{-1} (j+1)} \lvert f(y) - f(k^{-1} j) \rvert dy \leq \text{variation of } f \text{ over the interval } [k^{-1}j, k^{-1}(j+1))
$$
and
$$
\text{variation of } f \text{ over } [0,1) = \sum_j \text{variation of } f \text{ over } [k^{-1}j, k^{-1}(j+1))
$$
to get the desired bound.

Comment: This is not entirely following the derivations! Starting with a function $f\in L^1([0,1])$ you derive a bound for an arbitrary $L^1$ function on the circle by first starting with Fourier transform, but I am not sure why the $exp(-2\pi iky)$ dropped out in the third line. Also, it is not clear how the Fourier coefficients of a Holder continuous functions are bounded, starting from the general bound you gave on $L^1([0,1])$ functions. For bounded variation, I can certainly follow the intuition, but the proof/derivation is far from clean.

Comment: @Kernel_Dirichlet I will give you clarifications if you ask -- but beware my derivation left out steps for you to fill in on purpose. Indeed the steps I left out are used very often in analysis. For the third line, move the absolute value into the sum, and then into the integral, and use the fact that $\lvert e^{ix} \rvert = 1$. For the Holder continuous function, just apply the definition of Holder continuity. I have updated the bounded variation proof since I assumed continuity of $f$ in it originally.