# Fourier Coefficients of a Function of Bounded Variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-series, bounded-variation

I am working through a proof which bounds the coefficients of the Fourier series of a function of bounded variation, and ran into some difficulty.

The proof is given [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-04/S0002-9939-1967-0212477-6/S0002-9939-1967-0212477-6.pdf).

The only step which I am not understanding is the second to third line. How is it shown that $\int_{a_{k-1}}^{a_k} |f(x) - f(a_k)| dx \leq T(a_{k-1}, a_k) \frac{2\pi}{n}$, where T is the total variation ($\sup_{P} \Sigma |f(x_j) - f(x_{j-1})|)$?

I see that the $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ term comes from the fact that $a_k - a_{k-1} = \frac{2\pi}{n}$, but the fact that $f(a_k)$ is a constant is giving me trouble when I try to estimate the integral using Riemann sums and compare it to $T(a_{k-1}, a_k)$.

A similar question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211916/computing-decay-of-fourier-coefficients), but the answer does not give details on this calculation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, it belongs to the Mathematics community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{|n|}\int_{a_{k-1}}^{a_k} |f(x)-f(a_k)|\,dx
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{|n|} \max_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]} |f(x)-f(a_k)| \cdot\int_{a_{k-1}}^{a_k}\,dx\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{|n|} \max_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]} |f(x)-f(a_k)| \cdot \frac{2\pi}{n}
\end{align}
Which is Holder's inequality, followed by the result they introduce before the proof.

Now, clearly $[a_{k-1},x]\cup[x,a_k]$ is a partition of $[a_{k-1},a_k]$, hence by the definition of bounded variation,

$$|f(x)-f(a_k)|+|f(a_{k-1})-f(x)| \leq T(a_{k-1},a_k)$$
and therefore
$$\max_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]}|f(x)-f(a_k)|
\leq \max_{x\in[a_{k-1},a_k]}\left(|f(x)-f(a_k)| + |f(a_{k-1})-f(x)|\right)
\leq T(a_{k-1},a_k)$$